# JavaScript Chaining multiple createElement error

Tags: javascript, dom, createelement

Normally, I write my code like this:

```
var a = document.createElement('div');
var b = document.createElement('div');
a.appendChild(b);
```

This works. Now I tried to make it more compact:

```
var a,b;
a = b = document.createElement('div');
a.appendChild(b);
```

However, this way JS throws an error:

```
Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': The new child element contains the parent.
```

What is happening here?

Answer (score 1):

You assume that:

```
  a = b = document.createElement('div');
```

is the same as:

```
 a = document.createElement('div');
 b = document.createElement('div');
```

It isn't. It is rather the same as:

```
 b = document.createElement('div');
 a = b;
```

And therefore `a` and `b` are actually the same thing. To *copy* instead of *referencing* (if you really need a oneliner):

```
  a = (b = document.createElement('div')).cloneNode(false);
```

Or a oneliner for multiple:

```
  const [a, b, c, d] = Array.from({ length: 4 }, () => document.createElement("div"));
```

Comment: Actually, I tried to create more than two divs with a oneliner. But this way it gets too complicated.

Comment: `cloneNode` takes [exactly one argument](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-node-clonenode).